# How to create a list with an explicit type?

Tags: f#

```
type VAO(buffers) = 
    let handle = 
        let h = GL.GenVertexArray()
        GL.BindVertexArray(h)
        buffers 
        |> List.iter (fun (vbo : VBO) -> 
                       GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vbo.Pos)
                       vbo.Bind())
        GL.BindVertexArray(0)
        h
```

In this case `buffers` is of type `val buffers: VBO List` How do I get this type explicitly? If I try this `type VAO(buffers: VBO List)` I get `val buffers: List<VBO>` which is different and I can't use `List.iter` on this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close – `list`, lowercase `l`.